# google map two script clashing . how to join or use single one for both script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

1. Google map = `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>`
2. Autocomplete google map address =  `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
       async defer></script>`

I am not able to use both scripts together. Is there any solution.

Comment: the first script will not generate anything

Comment: Hi Molle, First one is simple a **google map script src** that used to show a google map and second one **google script src for autocomplete address**. I hope you have fare knowledge of google map.my question is fare and clear.

Comment: As I  said, the first script will not generate anything, it loads the maps-API but does not generate anything. When you  create a map somewhere you should provide that code too.

Comment: I got alternate solution. thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to think about the code as the one script?

```
<script
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation on libraries](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries)

> To request multiple libraries, separate them with a comma:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places">
</script>
```

If you want additional parameters in the URL, add them to the single include.